# what range should i use for the width

Tags: html, css

I have a main menu in my website. before the default font style was myriad pro light and the padding of main menu was:-

```
.menu > li > a { padding: 17px 15px 15px 15px; }
```

i changed the default font style to Montserrat. when i did that the main menu spoilt on my laptop screen. this is because padding right 15px and montesserat font made the main menu too wide and it didnt fit in the container and the last main menu item got pushed to new line. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_screen_width said that my screen width is 1366px

i changed the padding to:-

```
.menu > li > a { padding: 17px 7px 15px 15px; }
```

that worked on my screen and padding right 7px made the main menu extend almost to the full width of the container, but the problem is on bigger screen sizes like for example that have screen width 1538px and width 1600px and for those screens padding right 7px is too little and the main menu only extends to half the container width. on the bigger screen the padding should be:-

```
.menu > li > a { padding: 17px 35px 15px 15px; }
```

and padding right 35px will make the main menu extend almost to the full width of the container, but i cant say padding right 35px just like that or else it will spoil on my screen

the solution is to use css media queries by saying:-

```
@media only screen and (min-width: X) and (max-width: Y) {
    .menu > li > a {padding: 17px 7px 15px 20px}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: Z) {
    .menu > li > a {padding: 17px 35px 15px 20px}
}
```

that works, but the problem is i dont know what to put for X,Y and Z

http://mdsc1.ae/css/responsive.css is the responsive style sheet that i am using. there are style rules for different screen sizes. i looked at:-

## Base (1180 Grid)

## Desktop (960 Grid)

because those two apply for computer screens. the values that i used are X is 960px (that is minimum width for computer screen), Y is 1366px (that is width of my screen) and Z is 1367px (that is the minimum width that gets padding right 45px)

X is ok. i am not sure if i put the correct Y and Z. i am worried that the main menu could get corrupted on screen sizes that have bit bigger width like for example 1380px and for width 1380px the padding right should be 7px so that means my Y and Z values are wrong

what values of Y and Z should i put so the main menu is ok on all computer screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

> because padding right 15px and montesserat font made the main menu too
>   wide and it didnt fit in the container and the last main menu item got
>   pushed to new line.

You can change the padding for the last element like this:

```
.menu > li:last-child > a { padding-right: 0; }
```

But you need to know:

1. Web fonts can render differently on different browsers or devices, your design shouldn't be based on what you see on one device or browser.
2. If your menu going to be more than one line on specific resolution, you need to change the style of that menu to another type of menu. change it to the single drop down menu or make it as full screen menu by clicking on the menu icon.
3. For finding out what is the width or height of the view port you don't need other site to tell you that. you simple can go to the Chrome Developer Tools or install an extension to that for you.